# Eclipse: how to find the references of an inherited field (NOT the

Tags: java, eclipse

I am doing a Java project. I have a super class and it is inherited by many classes. For example:

```
SuperClass {
  private String field;
  public String getField() {
    return field;
  }

  public void setField(String field) {
    this.field = field;
  }
}

ChildClass1 extends SuperClass {
....
}

ChildClass2 extends SuperClass {
....
}
```

I simply need to find the references of getField method for ChildClasss1 (NOT all references including those for ChildClass2). How can I do that in Eclipse?

I tried in Eclipse and it reports all the references. Here is how I did: right-click on the use of the getField by a ChildClass1 object, and then select references and project.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I believe the OP wants to find all instances of the usage of ``ChildClass1.getField``. Without also getting instances of the usage of ``ChildClass2.getField`` and ``SuperClass.getField``.

Comment: Go into ChildClass2 and press Ctrl+Shift+G on an instance variable that it defines/defined in parent...

Comment: The problem is that Eclipse has no way to know that in a generic way, because any ``SuperClass`` could also be a ``ChildClass1``. So it doesn't even try. You could probably use a regex that searched for the text ``ChildClass1`` followed by any number of characters and then ``.getField``, but it's still not going to likely give you what you want.

Comment: Here's a very hacky way you could do this: temporarily remove `extends SuperClass` from `ChildClass1`. When Eclipse recompiles everything, look at all compilation errors targeting `ChildClass1.getField()`. Again, this is a hack that tells you what you need, not a real Eclipse feature.

Comment: musical_coder, thanks for your suggestion. musical_coder In my case, the SuperClass has more than just one field inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have two situations here.

1. new ChildClass1().parentClassMethod()
2. SuperClass sc = new ChildClass1(); sc.parentClassMethod();

In the first situation, you can make eclipse find all the method calls if you explicitly override parentClassMethod() in ChildClass1 and search from there.

In the second situation, there's no way to know that sc is a ChildClass1 instance in sc.parentClassMethod().

Comment: Leo, in your 1. new ChildClass2().parentClassMethod(). You mean new ChildClass1().parentClassMethod() according to my post, correct?

Comment: @curious1 as you wish :-) [fixed]